# Homology of twisted torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Consider a torus $T^2$ presented by the parallelogram with vertices $(0,0),(1,0),(n,1),(n+1,1)$. Its image in $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ is a torus with n twists. I'm wondering how such twisting affects the homology of the torus.

I took a $\Delta$-complex structure by cutting the original parallelogram into triangles with lines $x=k$ and $y=k/n$ for $0\leq k\leq n$. This seems to be unaffected under the quotient map, so I guess the twisted torus would actually have the same homology as the regular torus. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. If the original torus is represented by the region $[0,1]\times[0,1]/{\sim}$, then this 'twisted torus' can be made by a shear transformation, and you can actually construct such a homeomorphism that carries the rectangle to this parallelogram presentation.